# Limiting the number of records

Tags: django

I have one question, the answer I cant find in Google.

So, I have the model of cars (only char fields) and model of pictures of that cars:

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car,related_name='pictures')
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    main = models.BooleanField('Main Picture')
    def __unicode__(self):
         return str(self.id)
```

Its possible to do the following: I want only 4 pictures for one car. For example, BMW X5 - has only 4 pictures, and I cant add 5 pictures (from the admin interface). One car - 4 pictures (max). Its possible?
As you can see, I have field `main`, picture with this field=1 will apear in gallery, like a start picture in slide show. But I can add `main=1` for all pictures, and its wrong. So, its possible do the following:

```
1 car = 3 pictures(main=0) + 1 picture(main=1)
```

One car has 4 positions (max) in pictures table (4 pictures), and only one of that pictures has main=1. In admin interface I can add many pictures for one car and add main=1 for all pictures. How it can be limited?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...........

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        count = Pictures.objects.filter(main=True).count()
        if count <= 4:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: wow :) and how do only 1 of 4 main=1? `main = MyModel.objects.all().filter(main=1).count()` in new def with the same if? I do this, but I can add for all of 4 pictres main=1

Comment: just define Pictures in MyModel, it will count. and filter main=True

Comment: No, I need that user can add only one main=1, not main=1 for all of 4 pictures

Answer (score 0):

Validate your model with a custom form and clean method.

model.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', ...)
    main = models.BooleanField()

    # Distinguish between main and normal images
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.main:
            return "%s (main)" %self.image
        else:
            return self.image

class Car(models.Model):
    ...
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, blank=True, null=True, 
             related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", 
             help_text="Max 1 main image and max 4 images total.")
```

Then in your admin.py create a ModelForm with custom clean method:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Image, Car


class CarAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car

    def clean_images(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['images']
        if data.count() > 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Max 4 images.")
        if data.filter(main=True).count() > 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Max 1 main image.")
        return data

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CarAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['images', ]
    ...

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```

Bonus: to make a main image required:

```
        if not data.filter(main=True).count() == 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Exact 1 main image required!")
```

Comment: I just realized this question is old... @tim is my answer still useful?